# Hibernate query exception when using two foreign key relations

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. In the application I am working on chat functionality. You can think of chat functionality similar to facebook style. In this, there are conversations between two users and when conversation is loaded, one can see the texts inside. So I have 3 tables, User, Conversation, Replies. So Conversation only has two foreign key relations to user i.e sender and receiver.

Whenever a new message arrives, it is added in replies, with foreign key relation to conversation. THis way, whenever I need to load conversation, I just search for both users id, and load it from Replies.

Now When I am trying to search for conversationid in the database, I am searching for them using query, and I am getting an error. Error code goes below :

Error code :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userinfo_id of: com.WirTauschen.model.User [from com.WirTauschen.model.Messages as m where m.sender.id=:senderid and m.receiver.userinfo_id=:receiverid]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

User Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userinfo")
public class User implements UserDetails{

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "user_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name ="user_seq_gen", sequenceName = "user_seq")
public int id;


 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Messages> messages1 = new HashSet<Messages>();

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Messages> messages2 = new HashSet<Messages>();
```

// Getters and setters ommitted
    }

Messages model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversation")
public class Messages {
  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User sender;

  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userinfo_id")
    private User receiver;

// Getters and setters ommitted

}
```

MessagesDAOImpl :

```
@Override
    public Long returnConversationId(int senderid, int receiverid) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query1 = session.createQuery("from Messages as m where m.sender.id=:senderid and m.receiver.userinfo_id=:receiverid");
        query1.setParameter("senderid",senderid);
        query1.setParameter("receiverid",receiverid);
        List<Messages> firstDataList = query1.list();
        List<Messages> secondDataList = new ArrayList<Messages>();
        if(firstDataList.isEmpty()) {
            Query query2 = session.createQuery("from Messages as m where m.sender.id=:receiverid and m.receiver.userinfo_id=:senderid");
            query2.setParameter("senderid", senderid);
            query2.setParameter("receiverid", receiverid);
           secondDataList = query2.list();
        } else {
           for(Messages messages : firstDataList){
               return messages.getConversation_id();
           }
        }

        if(secondDataList.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        } else {
            for (Messages messages : secondDataList){
                return messages.getConversation_id();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

SQL Code :

```
CREATE TABLE userinfo
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  email character varying,
  username character varying,
  password character varying,
  accountstatus boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE conversation
(
  conversation_id numeric NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  userinfo_id integer NOT NULL,
  lastmessage character varying,
  CONSTRAINT conversation_id PRIMARY KEY (conversation_id),
  CONSTRAINT userinfo_conversation_fk FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES userinfo (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT userinfo_conversation_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (userinfo_id)
      REFERENCES userinfo (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Any pointers are welcome. Please note, there is a column in database with userinfo_id. Thank you.

Comment: I had to use two queries as I couldn't find any alternative for Union which is available in normal SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where is your "userinfo_id" in your model "User", you should have something like this :

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
```

and this in your message model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversation")
public class Messages {
  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User sender;

  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User receiver;

// Getters and setters ommitted

}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I want to check in database, if there are two foreign keys with sender and receiver id. I have added SQL code too, kindly have a look.